# NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger in Java applet

Tags: java, applet, log4j

At the moment, I'm developing java applet for e-signing documents with smartcard, current applet code on server side looks like

```
    echo "<Applet Code=\"Main.class\" 
        name = \"eParakstitajs\"
        mayscript=\"true\"
        codebase = \"".SERVER_FULL_URL."/EDOC2.4.0._22.05\"
        archive = \"
        classesEDOC2.4.jar,
        log4j-1.2.17.jar,
        eparaksts-bc-1.43.0.jar, 
        eparaksts-client-2.4.0.jar, 
        eparaksts-lib-2.4.0.jar, 
        org.apache.commons.codec_1.3.0.v201101211617.jar, 
        pkcs11wrapper-1.2.18.jar,
        plugin.jar, 
        signing-applet-2.4.0.jar, 
        slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar, 
        slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar, 

        xmlsec-2.0.2.jar, 

        ./config/\"  
        width=1 
        Height=1
          >
    <PARAM NAME=\"key\"         VALUE=\"{$signKey}\">
    <PARAM NAME=\"URL\"         VALUE=\"".SERVER_FULL_URL."\">
    <PARAM NAME=\"PIN1\"        VALUE=\"{$_SESSION["userdata"]["PIN1"]}\">
    <PARAM NAME=\"PIN2\"        VALUE=\"{$_SESSION["userdata"]["PIN2"]}\">
    <PARAM NAME=\"USERID\"      VALUE=\"{$user[0]["id_lietotajs"]}\">
</Applet>";
```

On this stage everything is ok, and all listed libraries are in mentioned folder. (ClassesEDOC2.4.jar is my archive with classes, all other are third-party jars)

In my java code, I am instantiating object, based on class QualifiedSignatureHelper from jar eparaksts-lib-2.4.0.jar. And during execution, an exception appears

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
    at lv.eparaksts.helpers.QualifiedSignatureHelper.<clinit>(QualifiedSignatureHelper.java:26)
    at CreateNewSignTimestampedAction.CreateNewSignTimestamped(CreateNewSignTimestampedAction.java:128)

    at Main.init(Main.java:221)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.init(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

I have decompiled class QualifiedSignatureHelper, and discovered that it imports log4j class, and also instantiating log4j object for some reasons

According to exception, QualifiedSignatureHelper class cant find log4j class. Any advice?